# Does Schedulers.io() run jobs synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: rx-java

According to the small [sample](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators) on the official documentation site, `ConnectableObservable` is supposed to run the operations associated with each observable at the same time.

But I'm studying this [sample code](https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/flatmap-concatmap-operators-flight-tickets-app/) and it seems like the work associated with each observer is run sequentially even though he is using the `ConnectableObservable`.

I'm thinking that it has to do with `Schedulers.io()` but this scheduler is backed by an unbounded thread pool so, in theory, it has more than a single thread available to do both workloads unless I'm missing something (which I definitely am).

> Does Schedulers.io() run jobs synchronously or asynchronously?

Or to put it another way:

> Why does the work associated with both observers run sequentially?
>
> Why the second observer is safe in assuming that the work associated with the first observer is done before it starts working on its own workload?

```java
    ConnectableObservable<List<Ticket>> ticketsObservable = getTickets(from, to).replay();

    /**
     * Fetching all tickets first
     * Observable emits List<Ticket> at once
     * All the items will be added to RecyclerView
     * */
    disposable.add(
            ticketsObservable
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Ticket>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Ticket> tickets) {
                            // Refreshing list
                            ticketsList.clear();
                            ticketsList.addAll(tickets);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            showError(e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    }));

    /**
     * Fetching individual ticket price
     * First FlatMap converts single List<Ticket> to multiple emissions
     * Second FlatMap makes HTTP call on each Ticket emission
     * */
    disposable.add(
            ticketsObservable
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    /**
                     * Converting List<Ticket> emission to single Ticket emissions
                     * */
                    .flatMap(new Function<List<Ticket>, ObservableSource<Ticket>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<Ticket> apply(List<Ticket> tickets) throws Exception {
                            return Observable.fromIterable(tickets);
                        }
                    })
                    /**
                     * Fetching price on each Ticket emission
                     * */
                    .flatMap(new Function<Ticket, ObservableSource<Ticket>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<Ticket> apply(Ticket ticket) throws Exception {
                            return getPriceObservable(ticket);
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Ticket>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Ticket ticket) {
                            int position = ticketsList.indexOf(ticket);

                            if (position == -1) {
                                // TODO - take action
                                // Ticket not found in the list
                                // This shouldn't happen
                                return;
                            }

                            ticketsList.set(position, ticket);
                            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            showError(e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    }));

    // Calling connect to start emission
    ticketsObservable.connect();
```

Comment: `Schedulers.io()` is anything but the main thread

Answer (score 2):

A `Scheduler` allows work to be run inside of an execution context; for `Scheduler.io()`, the context is a pool of threads. The `observeOn()` operator tells the observer chain to run within that context.

However, the way it works in practice is that only one thread is running the observer chain because that is all you asked it to use. Because `observerOn()` is only called once, when the observer chain is instantiated, only one thread is made available. If you instantiated the observer multiple times, each time it would select a thread from the pool and use that one thread for the specific instance.

## RxJava Is Not Multithreaded

There are rules about the workings of observer chains; among others, only one thread at a time can emit values into the chain. Any observer chain is normally executed entirely with a single thread, so that constraint is met by default.

### RxJava Controls Which Threads Are Active

With the use of `subscribeOn()`, `observeOn()` and other operators that implicitly or explicitly select a scheduler, you can control when and how work is divvied up among threads. It matters where you put these operators in the chain.

For instance, if you put the `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` operator **after** the first `flatMap()` operator, then you would get different results. `flatMap()` starts a new observer chain for every input; each observer chain would likely get its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I'm trying to unpack your answer and have a couple of questions as a result: First, you say "TheobserveOn() operator tells the observer chain to run within that context" isn't subscribeOn() the one that tells the observer chain on which context it should run and observeOn() is where you see the result for that "run"? What exactly do you mean when you say "instantiated the observer multiple times"? Isn't the observer instantiated multiple times in the sample code I posted? If rxjava is not multithreaded, why did the example in the official documentation behave as if it was?

Comment: `subscribeOn()` tells the observer chain where the head will run, if it runs asynchronously. The `observeOn()` operator affects processing **downstream** of its location in the chain. Since you have your `observerOn()` operator applied before the first `flatMap()`, that `flatMap()` will run on the one thread. If you add `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` downstream of `flatMap()`, that will affect the parallelism.

Comment: The best approach to determine what is running where is to add logging statements that print out the thread identifier, using `Thread.currentThread()`.

Comment: The sample in the official doc is not using flatMap but it still looks as if the both workloads are running concurrently, why is that? I'm just not seeing it yet.